# Unable to get context using getContext , when rendered a site not of valid domain in teams tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

I tried getting the context of personal tab of Microsoft teams using `microsoftTeams.getContext(context => { console.log(context);});`. I am able to get the context when I render the site from valid domains that i mentioned in the manifest.
But in case of cross domain scenarios, I am able to render the site in that teams tab, but unable to fetch the context of teams tab using the `getContext` of MicrosoftTeams SDK. Is there any limitation on fetching the teams tab context based on valid domains ( like context can only be fetched for valid domain )?

Comment: Did you initialize `microsoftTeams` before calling getContext?

Comment: yes,
In fact, I even tried giving some delay for fetching the context so that the microsoftTeams is initialized properly.
The snippet is as follows 
`microsoftTeams.initialize();
 setTimeout(function(){ microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => { console.log(context);})}, 100);`

Comment: How are you switching to other domain can you share minimal code snippet?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT, we are redirecting to other domain based on the user's input. After redirecting to that domain, On page load we initialized the microsoftTeams and tried fetching the context as mentioned above.

Comment: Redirecting with `document.location.href = URL;`?

Comment: After processing the user input, used `window.location.href = redirect_url;` for redirection.

Comment: I tried this and faced the same. After having domain in validDomains it starts showing theme. Can you tell you are also having the same behavior?

Comment: Yes. After adding the domain in valid domains, I was able to fetch the context. 
But I didn't get what you meant by showing theme. 
Can you confirm the behaviour of `getContext` in domains that are not listed under validDomains.?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected and it is for security concerns only. In order for a site to use `getContext` you need to define it in manifest's valid domain so that unwanted web app doesn't take advantage of that.

If you are using third party app and it navigates you to another web app then you wont want to give your information to it until you trust it. By adding domain in `validDomain` you are giving your consent that this domain can use context.